# Casting tail call void (i32, ...) bitcast to an llvm::Function to get the FnAttribute

Tags: c++, casting, llvm, llvm-ir

I have the following LLVM IR code:

```
 //Code snippet #1
; <label>:30:                                     ; preds = %30, %18
  tail call void (i32, ...) bitcast (void (...)* @delay to void (i32, ...)*)(i32 5) #3
  %31 = tail call zeroext i1 (...) @testFunc() #3
  br i1 %31, label %30, label %32
```

The first is a function call to the function Delay. It is a void function but I added FnAttributes to it. I did the same to testFunc but this one is returning a 1 bit integer (boolean).

When traversing the code like so:

```
//Code snippet #2
for (llvm::Instruction& inst : BB)
{
   llvm::CallInst * callInst = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::CallInst>(&inst);

    if (callInst == nullptr)
        continue;

    if (llvm::Function *calledFunction = callInst->getCalledFunction()) {
        if (calledFunction->hasFnAttribute("MyAttr")) {
            llvm::outs() << calledFunction.getFnAttribute("MyAttr").getValueAsString().str() << "\n";
        } 
    }
```

Getting the attribute (and printing it to the console) in the above code works for the testFunc but not for the void function. I need to be able to cast the void function to a llvm::Function to be able to get the FnAttribute.

Using something like

```
callInst->getCalledValue()
```

Gives me the value but I cannot cast it to an llvm::Function.

If I go through all functions by using the following code:

```
//Code snippet #3
for (llvm::Function& F : M)
{
    if (F.hasFnAttribute("MyAttr"))
        {
            llvm::outs() << F.getFnAttribute("MyAttr").getValueAsString().str() << "\n";
        }
}
```

I get the FnAttribute of the delay function just fine.

My question is: How can I get the "delay" function in this code casted to an llvm::Function so I can get the FnAttribute in code snippet #2?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So after some searching I found the solution to my own problem.

For those looking for the answer here it is. Also I found a way to get the type. It is included in the code below.

```
for (llvm::Instruction& inst : BB)
{
    llvm::CallInst * callInst = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::CallInst>(&inst);

    if (callInst == nullptr)
           continue;

    //this prints out "normal functions"
    if (llvm::Function *calledFunction = callInst->getCalledFunction()) {
                    llvm::outs() << "Call to => " << calledFunction->getName().str() << "\n";
    }
    //this prints out the void bitcasted functions
    else if (llvm::Function *voidFunc = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::Function>(callInst->getCalledValue()->stripPointerCasts())) {
                     llvm::outs() << "Call to => " << voidFunc ->getName().str() << "\n";
    }

    llvm::Type* t = callInst->getCalledValue()->getType();
    if (llvm::FunctionType* ft = llvm::cast<llvm::FunctionType>(llvm::cast<llvm::PointerType>(t)->getElementType()))
    { 
    //here is your function type
    }

}
```

**Explanation:**

1. First we cast the instruction to a Callinstruction (Callinst).
2. If it is a nullptr continue to the next iteration.
3. Try to cast it to a Function pointer.
4. Try to cast it if it is a bitcasted pointer. (this solves my issue).
5. To get the type you can use the getCalledValue()->getType() function
   and cast it to a FunctionType